# ECB custom action by visual studio

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, custom-actions, ecb-menu

How can I create a new ECB custom action by Visual Studio.
Which kind of project do I need to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a SharePoint Empty Project. Then Add Empty Element. Update the contents of the xml file. An example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction RegistrationType="ContentType" RegistrationId="0x01200032C6A02524ED43F5AD242743898508D800EAD428598B934BA88023591EFDAFF1A2006226422850DB44FE8E4D61D2F82B1193" Location="EditControlBlock" Sequence="106" Title="Manage Client Logo File" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/view.gif" Rights="EditListItems,AddListItems,DeleteListItems">
    <UrlAction Url="~site/_layouts/ClientLogoManagement.aspx?ItemUrl={ItemUrl}&amp;ListId={ListId}"/>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I pass the value field of the item in the UrlAction? (ex the Title)

Comment: Pass `ItemId={ItemId}`. It will give the item ID. Then use it to get the item and from that the Title field.