# ECB Custom Actions are not showing up

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, custom-actions, ecb-menu

So I'm trying to add two buttons to the ECB menu for a specfic document type. I've deployed and activated the feature but the actions are not showing up for my items. I'm using SharePoint 2016.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
      Id="{99AC145C-E692-43D5-B454-B0A2218BEEB4}"
      Title="Exclude From Pac"
      Description="Remove file from PAC"
      Location="EditControlBlock"
  RegistrationId="0x0101005054E241CF9E4F1D8A257FE403F3F4EC00FC7EDD99148D46BDBA8CB72D5A9408D400EEC1E3EB2E498541AE26535697BA6980"
      RegistrationType="ContentType"
      Sequence="101">
      <UrlAction Url="javascript:javascript:cca.pac.exclude(true, {ItemId})" />
  </CustomAction>
  <CustomAction
      Id="{09C1F9BF-67D3-4450-BF3C-92CEDA6A3DEF}"
      Title="Include in PAC"
      Description="Include file in PAC"
      Location="EditControlBlock"
      Sequence="301">
      <UrlAction Url="javascript:cca.pac.exclude(false, {ItemId})" />
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have followed below link for my implementation and working fine. Check your code with this it might help you

[ECB custom action by visual studio](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122089/ecb-custom-action-by-visual-studio)